# Постановка знаков препинания после "дожил"

Tags: пунктуация

"Дожил: разговариваю с птицами." (Пишется двоеточие, потому что в 2 части БСП идет пояснение, раскрытие смысла первой).
"Разговариваю с птицами - дожил." (Ставится тире, т.к. в 2 части БСП идет следствие, результат).
Все верно?

Comment: Спросите лучше здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com

Comment: Вроде верно. Хотя и в первом случае тоже можно ставить тире, я считаю.

Answer (score 1):

Я не думаю, что **дожил** во втором примере — это результат. Это, скорее, просто вывод из наблюдения в первой части. Но тире тут вполне уместно.

Сам вопрос в заголовке сформулирован не очень аккуратно. Речь идет не о тире после **дожил**, а о тире между двумя частями `сложноподчиненного предложения`.